# How to give site id or site name in Search in Expression Engine(bug in expression engine)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Search functionality is not working for multiple sites i have three website

**eg.**

```
1)example1.com
2)example2.com
3)example3.com
```

the (2) and (3) no. site is taking data from site (1) but search is only working on site (1) not on others two its redirecting to `no_result_page="search/no_results"`

```
{exp:search:simple_form
    channel="default_site:news|business|travel"
    result_page="search/results"
    no_result_page="search/no_results"         
    search_in="everywhere"}

    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="search" value="" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" required /> 

    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>

{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

So I want to know anything else i have to add in this above code

Thanks in advance.